# Как правильно парсить json C#

Tags: c#, json

Есть json, в котором хранятся точки, из которых, в последствии, строятся определенные 3d объекты, по сути координаты вершин. Особенность в том что лежат они на неравномерной глубине.

[image: скриншот куска json'a]

Как видно в 31-ом "наборе" точек они лежат сразу после узла "coordinates" а в 32-ом после этого узла они делятся еще на 2 группы, а внутри группы уже искомый набор точек.
Задача состоит в том что бы дойти по узлам до элементов составляющих наборы точек (зеленые элементы являются координатами собственно x y), собрать точки принадлежащие одному набору в список, отправить их на обработку и дальше двигаться по json'у. Сложность в том, что там где они делятся на группы (32-ой), надо каждую группу элементов отправлять отдельно, как если бы это была законченная (как в случае с 31-ой, прошлись по 0,1,2 собрали точки внутри отправили пошли дальше), то есть зайти 32-geometry->coordinates->0 все что внутри собрать и отправить затем в 32-geometry->coordinate->1 собрать отправить, затем только дальше. Логично было бы предположить что там где type: MultiLineString можно просто добавить еще один цикл прохода по элементам, но что то мне подсказывает что я неверно рассуждаю. Как решить эту задачу правильно с точки зрения практик парсинга json файлов?

Извините за сумбурное описание, пытался детализировать как мог.

update вот таким образом я пытался добраться до необходимых мне данных, но данные из 32-ой группы сливались в один list и я так и не придумал как ПРАВИЛЬНО, мне их получить. Сейчас я понимаю судя по комментариям и ответам что я подобрался к задаче с принципиально не той стороны.

```
private void CreateRoads(JSONObject mapData)
    {
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var geo in mapData["features"].list)
        {
            count++;
            var l = new List<Vector3>();


            for (int i = 0; i < geo["geometry"]["coordinates"].list.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!geo["geometry"]["coordinates"][i][0].IsNumber)
                {

                    for (int j = 0; j < geo["geometry"]["coordinates"][i].list.Count; j++)
                    {
                        var c = geo["geometry"]["coordinates"][i][j];
                        var bm = GM.LatLonToMeters(c[1].f, c[0].f);
                        var pm = new Vector2(bm.x - Rect.center.x, bm.y - Rect.center.y);
                        l.Add(pm.ToVector3xz());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var c = geo["geometry"]["coordinates"][i];
                    var bm = GM.LatLonToMeters(c[1].f, c[0].f);
                    var pm = new Vector2(bm.x - Rect.center.x, bm.y - Rect.center.y);
                    l.Add(pm.ToVector3xz());
                }
            }

            var m = new GameObject("road_" + count.ToString()).AddComponent<RoadPolygon>();
            m.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(m.transform.localPosition.x, m.transform.localPosition.y + 1f, m.transform.localPosition.z);
            m.transform.parent = this.transform;
            try
            {
                m.Initialize(geo["properties"]["id"].str, this, l, geo["properties"]["kind"].str);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Log(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

с десериализацией я справился, спасибо @sp7, но как разрулить разные уровни глубины у блоков пока не пойму. Что бы это было универсально, а не хардкодом. Есть мысли на тему прохода в глубину до последнего узла (отличается тем что у него чайлдов видимо) от него вверх на уровень, собираем искомые данные (списки с координатами), отправляем, уровень вверх выходим, смотрим есть ли еще на это же уровне какие то списки, нету снова вверх если вышли до блока coordinates, то переходим к следующему номеру (33,34,35) и тд...вот беда только в том что я не знаю как такой проход в глубину сделать. И гугление не помогло особо =/

```
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(www.text);
        var features = root.roads.features;
        List<object[][]> coordinates = new List<object[][]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < features.Length; i++)
        {
            coordinates.Add(features[i].geometry.coordinates);
        }
        ConstructRoad(coordinates);
```

Comment: Вы бы выложили ваш json в текстовом виде для экспериментов. Вы ж не ожидаете, что мы реконструируем json вручную по картинке?

Comment: И ещё, непонятно, почему вы работаете с json напрямую. Почему бы не десериализировать сначала в объектную структуру?

Comment: @VladD добавил пример кода и мысли по поводу своих действий

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Позволю себе высказаться. Как ранее было замечено, для того что бы было удобно работать с `Json` данными, их нужно как минимум десериализовать в объектный вид.

Поэтому:

1) Если у вас есть эти `Json` данные в текстовом виде (`string`) скопируйте их в буфер обмена. Если данных в текстовом виде нет, получите их откуда-то из вне, преобразуйте в строку (как вариант, `JObject.Parse().ToString()`) и скопируйте в буфер обмена.

2) Создайте пустой `С#` файл, в нем не должно быть ничего, кроме указания `namespace`. Курсор ставим внутрь `namespace`.

3) Затем в Visual Studio заходим в меню `Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes`.

4) Вуаля!!! Visual Studio создала за вас классы, которые представляют указанные `Json` данные.

5) Теперь когда классы `С#` готовы, Вы можете ваши `Json` данные используя `JsonSerializer` десериализовать в ту объектную модель, что за вас создала студия.

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonStr);
```

6) Ну и в завершении, теперь Вы просто можете работать с данными в удобном виде.

Comment: Спасибо! Я сейчас попробую так сделать!

Comment: А мне необходимо весь json целиком копировать при этом или я могу выделить именно необходимый блок? Я к тому, что если мне не нужны все данные, то все равно необходимо описывать все целиком в классе,  а там уже походу дело выуживать нужное?

Comment: Лучше скопируйте весь, что бы структура была сформирована правильно. Далее когда студия сгенерирует нужны классы, Вы всегда сможете руками выпилить из них ненужные члены.

Comment: обновил описание вопроса. Я не прошу готового решения а хотя бы куда рыть и с чем ознакомиться.

Comment: Он у Вас рекурсивно не десериализует?

Comment: я видимо некорректно выразился в описании задачи. Как видно на скриншоте есть группы 31, 32, каждая из таких групп это описание того  или иного объекта. Их объединяет то что в каждой из них есть Coordinates, как логично предположить описание координат объекта. Мне необходимо получая координаты(массивы пар точек (x,y)) каждого отдельно взятого объекта передавать их дальше. А хитрость в том что в группе 32 как можно заметить координаты делятся на 2 группы, а массивы координат уже непосредственно внутри этих групп.

Comment: Объект фактически состоит из двух строений и соответственно эти пачки координат нужно передавать по отдельности что бы построить по ним 2 разных объекта. Вот сложность как раз в написании метода обхода который дошел бы до координат, собрал  их передал дальше, сложность связана именно с разной глубиной вложенности конечных данных.

Comment: Я реализовал это на уровне проверки geometry.type = "LineString" или "MultiLineString" и в зависимости от этого глубина прохода зависит, но хотелось бы понять как реализовать это универсально. Если добавится еще один уровень глубины данных то уже начнутся костыли, а этого не хочется.

Comment: А в вашем проекте данная универсальность оправдана? Вы ведь поймите золотое правило, что не нужно мудрить там, где этого не требуется, иначе решение может получиться сложным и трудно поддерживаемым. Поэтому в первую очередь исходите из контекста решаемой задачи. Относительно того как сделать, что бы не завязываться на `LineString` и `MultiLineString` и вытаскивать при этом данные наборы координат, то Вам придется использовать рефлексию и рекурсивно анализировать свойства конкретного типа и проверять не хранит ли свойство тип представляющий координату.

Comment: В этом направлении я и рыл. Находясь на текущей позиции проверял тип данных у чайлдов чайлда, если это было не число то тогда заходил на уровень глубже, в противно случае собирал координаты. Проблемы возникли именно с рекурсией(банально на уровне понимания как правильно ее реализовать). Спасибо за подробный ответ, действительно, в текущих реалиях решения оказались одинаковыми по объему и сложности.

Comment: Ну по факту вам нужно анализировать только комплексные `public` типы и пропускать простые вроде `int`, `byte`, `bool` и т.п. Т.е. берете конкретный тип, через рефлексию вытаскиваете из него все `public` свойства и отбрасываете из этих полученных свойств все свойства `простого типа`. Как только видите, что тип свойства комплексный аналогично анализируете все свойства в нем. Если сталкиваетесь с тем, что свойство какого-то типа это коллекция (массив, список) смотрите, что за тип в нем хранится. Следовательно, если список хранит тип, представляющий координату - это то, что Вы искали. Как-то так.

Answer (score 2):

Взгляните вот [тут](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm), как десериализуются части JSON...

Здесь делается общий парсинг, а затем можно переходить на уровни и десериализовать их вот так :

```
JObject googleSearch = JObject.Parse(googleSearchText);

// get JSON result objects into a list
        IList<JToken> results = googleSearch["responseData"]["results"].Children().ToList();

// serialize JSON results into .NET objects
IList<SearchResult> searchResults = new List<SearchResult>();

foreach (JToken result in results)
{
    SearchResult searchResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchResult>(result.ToString());
    searchResults.Add(searchResult);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо я немедленно ознакомлюсь с информацией :)