# Не выходит распарсить JSON с помощью Newtonsoft JSON

Tags: c#, json, winforms

Господа, не выходит распарсить с JSON вида:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "",
    "result": [
        {
            "MarketName": "BTC-DCR",
            "High": 0.00276762,
            "Low": 0.00261059,
            "Volume": 2011.69194218,
            "Last": 0.002637,
            "BaseVolume": 5.33707839,
            "TimeStamp": "2016-08-08T22:02:25.687",
            "Bid": 0.002637,
            "Ask": 0.00270211,
            "OpenBuyOrders": 148,
            "OpenSellOrders": 809,
            "PrevDay": 0.00269298,
            "Created": "2016-02-09T21:06:51.577"
        }
    ]
}
```

Юзаю Newtonsoft JSON.
Пытаюсь вот так:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(jsondcrbtc);
dcr_to_btc = Convert.ToString(o["result"]["Last"]);
```

*Что я не так делаю?*

Comment: `o["result"][0]["Last"]`

Comment: Аналогичная проблема решалась здесь http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/551479/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-c/551573#551573 возможно предложенное там решение подойдет и Вам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Result
{
    public string MarketName { get; set; }
    public double High { get; set; }
    public double Low { get; set; }
    public double Volume { get; set; }
    public double Last { get; set; }
    public double BaseVolume { get; set; }
    public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public double Bid { get; set; }
    public double Ask { get; set; }
    public int OpenBuyOrders { get; set; }
    public int OpenSellOrders { get; set; }
    public double PrevDay { get; set; }
    public string Created { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
}

public static class Class1
{
    public static string js = "{" +
                "\"success\": true," +
                "\"message\": \"\"," +
                "\"result\": [" +
                " {" +
                "\"MarketName\": \"BTC-DCR\"," +
                "\"High\": 0.00276762," +
                "\"Last\": 0.002637," +
                "\"Created\": \"2016-02-09T21:06:51.577\"" +
                "}" +
                "]" +
                "}";
    public static void run()
    {

        JObject o = JObject.Parse(js);
        RootObject obj = new RootObject();
        obj.result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Result>>(o.Root["result"].ToString());
        foreach (var ro in obj.result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Last: {ro.Last}");
            Console.WriteLine($"High: {ro.High}");
        }
    }
}
```

Код классов `Result` и `RootObject` автоматически сгенерирован [тут](http://json2csharp.com/#) по образцу представленного JSON.

Comment: Спасибо, это работает :)

Answer (score 0):

У Вас в JSON `"result"` является массивом, поэтом, прежде чем брать значение `"Last"`, необходимо определиться к какому элементу массива Вы обращаетесь.

Answer (score 0):

Понимаю что устарело, но полностью рабочий кусок.) Простой и примитивный:

```
async public void GetData(string pair)
{
    string queryStr = string.Format("https://btc-e.nz/api/2/{0}/ticker", pair);
    var client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(queryStr));
    var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var resultat = JObject.Parse(jsonString)["ticker"];
    data = (string)resultat["last"]; 
}
```