# C#- Как десериализировать Json в котором есть массив?

Tags: c#, json, vkontakte-api

Всем привет!  Есть Json получаемый от LongPoll`а ВКонтакте:

```
{
"ts": 17233564,
"updates": [
    [51, 5, 0],
    [7, 20000005, 19335],
    [4, 19336, 8193, 2000005, 1497039161, "", {
        "source_act": "chat_title_update",
        "source_text": "Test2",
        "source_old_text": "Test",
        "from": "3023232"
    }]
]}
```

Как  Как десериализировать подобный json?

Comment: это словарь....

Comment: @codename0082016, не совсем. Это массив, но он не строго типизирован, поэтому только в object или dynamic

Comment: @codename0082016 , В документации ВКонтакте сказано, что updates представляет собой массив

Comment: Ну да, updates  - массив с разными объектами

Comment: количество элементов всегда одинаковое?

Comment: @codename0082016 нет. Разное

Comment: @Fooxboy, ну а dynamic пробовали?

Comment: ...в какую структуру нужно десериализовать? может быть проще просто разобрать `json`  чем играться с десериализацией?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper И как его "проще просто разобрать"?

Comment: @Fooxboy linq2json например, вы структуру скажите - пример напишу

Comment: другими словами какая информацию из данного json вам нужна?

Comment: Скопировать этот json в буфер обмена, в Студии выбрать в меню: Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes. Генерируется класс с двумя свойствами типа int и массив массивов. Потом всё замечательно десериализуется.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да это понятно, другой вопрос насколько удобно потом с таким классом будет работать

Comment: В свое время, отвечал на подобный вопрос, детали можно посмотреть здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/551573/16781

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будет понадобиться http://json2csharp.com/ для получения класса (или коммент @Alexander Petrov), а потом `Newtonsoft JSON Nuget` для десериализировать `json`

http://json2csharp.com/ **класс :**

```
public class LongPoll
{
    public int ts { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> updates { get; set; }
}
```

`Newtonsoft JSON Nuget` **десериализировать :**

```
LongPoll longpoll = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LongPoll>(json);
```

Comment: отличный набор классов, самое главное с ним так удобно работать!