# C# создать список объектов из дессериализации дерева объектов JSON

Tags: c#, json, uwp, json.net

Сразу хочу сказать, что я начинающий разработчик и прошу прощения, если вопрос поставлен не корректно. Нигде не нашел, как обратится к вложенному объекту JSON.

Мне необходимо вытянуть из очень большого JSON файла определенные строки, объединить в объект и собрать в список объектов. 
Не выходит написать класс с необходимыми параметрами. 
Вот небольшая часть JSON:

```
  "result": [
{
  "id": 13,
  "identity": "",
  "way": "reduction",
  "proc": "open",
  "state": "started",
  "title": "Молот Тора",
  "description": "",
bla-bla-bla
]
  "entityType": "bidding",
  "owner": {
    "personId": 38,
    ...
    "subjectRole": "OWNER",
    "personContractorId": 38,
    "contractorId": 38,
    "contractorName": "Фьюри Ник Фф",
    "contractorAvatarId": 49,
    "contractorAvatarUrl": "...",
    "coverFileId": 50,
    "coverFileUrl": "...",
    "contractorType": "PERSON",
    "contractorTypeCompany": ""
  }
},{
  "id": 15,...
```

Вот в этом месте у меня и возникла проблема. Не уверен, видно ли это из скопированной части JSON, но "result" это корневой объект внутрь которого вложен объект "owner", внутри которого часть нужных мне полей. 
Для работы с JSON написал вот такой класс:

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;

    namespace BackgroundTasks
    {
        [Serializable]
        public sealed class Bid
        {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "entityType")]
        public string EntityType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "proc")]
        public string Process { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "owner")]
        public object Owner { get; set; }

        public Bid() { }

        public Bid(string entityType, string title, string process, int id, object owner)
        {
            EntityType = entityType;
            Title = title;
            Process = process;
            Id = id;
            Owner = owner;
        }
    }
    [Serializable]
    public sealed class BidOwner
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "contractorName")]
        public string ContractorName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "contractorAvatarUrl")]
        public string LogoUrl { get; set; }

        public BidOwner() { }

        public BidOwner(string contractorName, string logoUrl)
        {
            ContractorName = contractorName;
            LogoUrl = logoUrl;
        }
    }
}
```

Поля из "owner" не тянулись(видно на скрине), когда был только class Bid, в котором были перечислены все поля.

GET запросом я получаю string jsonText и далее:

```
var json = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
List<JToken> result = json["result"].Children().ToList();
        IList<Bid> bidSearchResults = new List<Bid>();
        foreach (JToken res in result)
        {
            Bid searchResult = res.ToObject<Bid>();
            bidSearchResults.Add(searchResult);
        }
```

Скрин:[Должно быть так, но с заполненными полями](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqBnl.jpg)

Скрин:[А получается вот так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6lad.jpg)

Comment: Прочтите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/551573/16781

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо большое за ссылку. Она вдохновила меня на собственное решение. Сразу хочу извинится за некоторое незначительное несоответствие имен переменных с теми, которые приведены в вопросе, но я экспериментировал и и по сути все будет ясно.

Нашел 2 решения. **Решение №1**:
Внимательно изучив данные я понял, что в цикле "foreach (JToken res in result)" - "res" содержит нужную нам информацию для получения єлементов из вложенного объекта (что нам и нужно). Для большего понимания:
Когда мы вытащили в список "var resultList" содержимое "result" мы опустились на уровень глубже. Вот в этом месте:

```
var resultList = json["result"].Children().ToList();
```

Таким образом, каждый элемент нашего списка выглядит так же как jsonText, но на уровень глубже и не в стринге. 
Я привел элемент "res" к стрингу и получилось, что для полей JSON объекта "owner" мы получили ту же ситуацию, как изначально для полей JSON объекта "result". 
Дальше уже дело техники. Для корректной работы всей этой красоты так же поправил модель "Bid" (теперь называется "Bidding"). Немного кода:

```
        var json = JObject.Parse(jsonText);

        // собираем JSON в список объектов resultList 
        var resultList = json["result"].Children().ToList();
        //результат работы цикла:
        var biddingSearchResults = new List<Bidding>();

        foreach (var res in resultList)
        {
                var searchBidOwner = res.ToString();
                var json1 = JObject.Parse(searchBidOwner);
                //делаем то же самое, что и для ["result"], но приводим сразу в ToObject<Bidding> так как предварительная работа уже выполнена
                var ownerList = json1["owner"].ToObject<Bidding>();
                //совмещаем содержимое объектов:
                Bidding searchResult = res.ToObject<Bidding>();
                searchResult.ContractorName = ownerList.ContractorName;
                searchResult.LogoURL = ownerList.LogoURL;
                biddingSearchResults.Add(searchResult);                
        }
```

И вот так теперь выглядит Bidding:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace BackgroundTasks
{
    [Serializable]
    public sealed class Bidding
    {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "entityType")]
    public string EntityType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "proc")]
    public string Process { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "contractorName")]
    public string ContractorName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "contractorAvatarUrl")]
    public string LogoURL { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "state")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    public Bidding() { }

    public Bidding(string entityType, string title, string process, string contractorName, string logoURL, int id, string state)
    {
        EntityType = entityType;
        Title = title;
        Process = process;
        ContractorName = contractorName;
        LogoURL = logoURL;
        Id = id;
        State = state;
    }

}
```

}

Результат:

[image: Получили именно то, что нужно]

Есть гораздо более простая для понимания альтернатива.
**Решение №2**:

Создаем модель "Owner"

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace BackgroundTasks
{
    [Serializable]
    public sealed class Owner
    {

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "contractorName")]
        public string ContractorName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "contractorAvatarUrl")]
        public string LogoURL { get; set; }

        public Owner() { }

        public Owner(string contractorName, string logoURL)
        {
            ContractorName = contractorName;
            LogoURL = logoURL;
        }

    }
}
```

В модель Bidding добавляем:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "owner")]
public Owner Owner { get; set; }
```

Наш код теперь выглядит вот так (комменты убрал для компактности):

```
    var json = JObject.Parse(jsonText);            
    var resultList = json["result"].Children().ToList();

    var biddingSearchResults = new List<Bidding>();

    foreach (var res in resultList)
    {
            var searchResult = res.ToObject<Bidding>();
            biddingSearchResults.Add(searchResult);
        }
```

Естественно, такой вариант компактнее, но и результат отличается:
*(да, я знаю, что из Bidding лишнее можно удалить)*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

На этом [сайте](http://json2csharp.com/) можно удобно генерировать модели из любого Json. Потом десериализуете json в нужную модель и обращаетесь как с классами. И никакой логики писать не надо.

Comment: Да, видел этот сайт. Возможно не понял, как использовать результат (комментарий, к стаи тоже не совсем понял), но он сформировал для меня огромную модель. Разве при проведении дессериализации мы не получим огромный ветвистый объект (возможно я не прав)? Если так - в чем же логика? + если структура JSON изменится хоть незначительно, как я понимаю, придется заново генерить такой класс? Или я не прав?

Comment: Да, при изменении структуры json многое может сломаться, но это плата за строгую типизацию. И она крайне редко меняется внезапно без предупреждения. Чтобы не создавать ветвистый объект, можно взять только нужные части иерархии, остальное будет отсеиваться при десериализации.