# Десериализация многомерного json

Tags: c#, json

Есть json, для которого я сгенерировал класс.

```
[{"geo":"EG","impressions":0,"clicks":1944,"revenue":1.3219},{"geo":"NZ","impressions":0,"clicks":28,"revenue":0.0337},
..
```

.

```
public class Reporo
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string geo { get; set; }
    public int impressions { get; set; }
    public int clicks { get; set; }
    public float revenue { get; set; }
}
```

Я пытаюсь десериализовать исходную json-строку в класс, однако в переменной reporoData есть n-элементов, но в них ничего не содержится.

```
var reporoData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Reporo>>(json);
```

Если я же сделаю десериализацию в`List<object>`, то данные появляются, однако навигация в них вызывает проблему.

Comment: Что значит `данные появляются, однако навигация в них вызывает проблему` и почему вы не используете `Newtonsoft Json`?

Comment: @sp7 так ведь `object` ;)

Comment: @sp7 Использую System.Web.Extensions

Comment: @FoggyFinder да все верно) мне проще его  в list<reporo> сконвертировать, нежели по object-ам проходиться.

Comment: @Radzhab покажите ваш `JSON`

Comment: @sp7 исправил...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С той структурой `JSON` данных, который вы привели вам необходимо десериализовать в коллекцию типа `Class1`.

```
var reporoData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Class1>>(s);
```

Если вы хотите десериализовать в коллекцию типа `Reporo` ваши `JSON` данные должны выглядеть так:

```
"[{\"Property1\":[{\"geo\":\"EG\",\"impressions\":0,\"clicks\":1944,\"revenue\":1.3219}]}]";
```

Кроме того, для того что бы легко и просто создавать классы из `JSON` данных, вы можете воспользоваться следующей информацией - [читать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/551573/16781).

Comment: thx...............................