# JSON не хочет парситься в класс! C#

Tags: c#, json, парсер

Делаю бота Телеграмм. При парсинге через `Newtonsoft.json` выдает ошибку. Вот все использованные материалы. JSON данные:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "result": [{
            "update_id": 787055778,
            "message": {
                "message_id": 1,
                "from": {
                    "id": 420474275,
                    "is_bot": false,
                    "first_name": "Name;",
                    "username": "User"
                },
                "chat": {
                    "id": 420474275,
                    "first_name": "Name;",
                    "username": "User",
                    "type": "private"
                },
                "date": 1544978929,
                "text": "/start",
                "entities": [{
                        "offset": 0,
                        "length": 6,
                        "type": "bot_command"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Код парсинга:

```
        public static void GetUpdates()
    {
        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            string update = webClient.DownloadString($"https://api.telegram.org/bot{Token}/getUpdates");
            var parsedUpdate = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(update);
        };
    }

public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public Dictionary<string, Result> Result { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("0")]
    public Dictionary<string, Zero1> Zero1 { get; set; }
}

public class Zero1
{
    [JsonProperty("update_id")]
    public string UpdateID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public Dictionary<string, Message> Message { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    [JsonProperty("message_id")]
    public string MessageID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("from")]
    public Dictionary<string, From> From { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("entities")]
    public Dictionary<string, Entities> Entities { get; set; }
}

public class From
{
    [JsonProperty("is_bot")]
    public string IsBot { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class Entities
{
    [JsonProperty("0")]
    public Dictionary<string, Zero2> Zero2;
}

public class Zero2
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Вот ошибка:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,Бот_викторина_1.Result]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: Вот ошибка:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,Бот_викторина_1.Result]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: Вы приложили битый пример json. К тому же, как мне кажется, Data.Result должен иметь тип List<Result>. Возможно еще что то есть. приложите корректный ответ json

Comment: Ну так в сообщении же всё написано.

Comment: Иногда есть смысл воспользоваться функцией VS : Edit-> Past Special -> Past JSON As Classes. Это может сократить время создания модели и защитить вас от "человеческого фактора"

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно парсить json C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/551479/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-c)

Answer (score 3):

Не правильно сформировали код.

```
var parsedUpdate = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(update);
```

```C#
public class From
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool is_bot { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
}

public class Chat
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Entity
{
    public int offset { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public int message_id { get; set; }
    public From from { get; set; }
    public Chat chat { get; set; }
    public int date { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public List<Entity> entities { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public int update_id { get; set; }
    public Message message { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public bool ok { get; set; }
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
}
```